# Given a laurent series, how do we show it doesnt have a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

Ive been given a Laurent series and told to show that it doesn't have a pole at z = 0, I tried finding the function the Laurent series represents but that is too complex is there any other way to show the series doesn't have a pole at a certain point?

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{-2^n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{z^n}$

Comment: A pole at $z = 0$ would be a term (single or finite number of terms) in the series that look(s) like $1/z^n$.

Comment: That's currently my issue on of the terms in the series is n/z^n so Im not sure how to prove there isn't any pole?

Comment: Can you attach a picture of the series to your question?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: Well, it looks like it has infinite number of terms that look like $1/z^n$.  So, definitely not a pole.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that, when z= 0 there would be infinite terms which of the form $1/z^n$ doesn't that indicate a pole (by your definition above)?

Comment: An infinite number of negative degree terms in a Laurent expansion indicates an essential singularity, where as a pole must only have finitely many such terms.

Comment: thankyou! that clears up the confusion

Comment: The series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{z^n}=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ for $|z|\gt1$. However, for $|z|\lt1$, it does not converge, so we can't really say much about its behavior near $z=0$. It's analytic continuation does not have a singularity at all at $z=0$ because it vanishes there.

Comment: The function is $\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}+\frac2{z-2}$ in the annulus $1\lt|z|\lt2$. The analytic continuation has poles at $z=1$ and $z=2$.

Comment: The situation elucidated by @robjohn might be described as the function having a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) at $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In effect, having a pole of order $m$ is the same thing as the Laurent expansion

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {b_n} {(z-z_0)^{n}}$$

having the nonzero coefficient $b_m$ but every coefficient after $m$ is zero.

In your example, we have a nonzero coefficeint $b_1 = 1$ and nonzero coefficient $b_2= 2$ and so on.  In fact, the coefficients for the terms with negative exponent $(z-z_0)^{-n}$ have infinitely many nonzero coefficients.  (Note: here $z_0 = 0$.)

Therefore the point $z=0$ is not a pole but is in fact an essential singularity.  In fact this is often the definition of an essential singularity.

[Edit: @robjohn is right, I should have paid attention to the domain of convergence.  Since this series does not converge in any neighborhood of $z=0$ then we cannot read off the pole at $z=0$.  Strictly speaking the given series is not defined interior to $|z|<1$ and it makes no sense to talk about singularities or other properties inside this region.  So strictly speaking, this explains why the given series has no pole at the point $z=0$.]

Comment: Be careful. The series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{z^n}=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ does not converge for $|z|\lt1$, so how can you say it has an essential singularity at $z=0$? The analytic continuation of the function represented by the series for $|z|\gt1$ has a zero at $z=0$.